# pthread_cond_broadcast warning even if condition is never satisfied

Tags: c++, pthreads, warnings

I have a warning, even when the condition is never satisfied. For example:

```
if ( false )
    pthread_cond_broadcast(0);
```

gives me the following g++ warning:

```
warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1)
```

Is there a way i can avoid that? Is this normal?
Thanks

Comment: I really hope that that code is part of a macro expansion—if not, just delete it, since the parameter passed to `pthread_cond_broadcast` must be non-null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume this is being expanded from a function-like macro? If that's the case, you could use an inline function instead, and the warning will go away.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed the case..Although i cannot use an inline function since there are 2 macros : one using pthread_push_cleanup() and the other pthread_pop_cleanup(). Unfortunably those functions ought to be in the same code block scope.

Comment: You might just have to wrap the `pthread_cond_broadcast()` in an inline function then, something like: `inline int null_or_broadcast(pthread_cond_t *cond) { return cond ? pthread_cond_broadcast(cond) : 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

In your system, `<pthread.h>` may have following declaration of `pthread_cond_broadcast` with [`nonnull` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) for GCC.

```
int pthread_cond_broadcast(pthread_cond_t *cond) __attribute__((nonnull));
```

Anyway `pthread_cond_broadcast` does NOT accept null pointer(NULL, 0, nullptr).